# Another Easy Mate in 1

Tags: no-computers, chess

[image: 1Bb3BN/R2Pk2r/1Q5B/4q2R/2bN4/4Q1BK/1p6/1bq1R1rb w - - 0 1]

Standard chess rules apply, the board is not rotated (i.e. white pawns move upwards), no lateral thinking is needed. Simply find the one move for white which mates the black king.

---

*This puzzle was created by [Leonid Kubbel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonid_Kubbel).*

Comment: Are there two queens each(of black and white)?

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay apparently so, it appears some pawns have promoted.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Yes, and 4 bishops, 3 rooks, ...

Comment: See about the 29 minute mark in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0saFg21rbY8, where grang master Ben Finegold "analyses" this exact puzzle (he talks about it for a few minutes, at least).

Comment: man, chess puzzles are extremely popular on this site.

Comment: @Arthur I came here to post Ben Finegold and I wasn't dsappointed. Very suspicious.

Comment: @thecoder16 Good, because those are the only ones I can solve. I feel like an idiot whenever I come here

Comment: Why is this here instead of on chess.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @M.M You could ask a similar question about any math puzzle here. Regarding chess puzzles at least the "funny" ones are considered on topic here. According to a meta post serious chess puzzles should be posted on chess.se, but I don't see any puzzles posted there regularly, which makes me doubt if they are welcome there at all.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's simple:

> Move the queen on e3 to a3

This gives the position:

> [image: Lichess board editor]

which is clearly mate.

NB:

> The black queen on e5 is pinned by the white rook on e1, so it can't intercept.

Comment: Correct, I needed way longer than you to find the move.

Comment: @Sleafar I find with these problems you just need to find the obvious trap squares, then get around them.

Comment: I was quite busy with the red herring on d7.

Comment: i'm wondering if moving the bishop in g3 to h4 is a winning move too, as only the black queen can intercept it

Comment: What is the problem with queening the pawn d7-d8?

Comment: @Chris It's pinned by the bishop

Comment: Aha! Of course. I spent so long looking for how black could get out of it that I completely forgot to check if it was a legal move! :)

Comment: @Neil Rg5 blocks that check.

Comment: what is wrong with e3 queen to g5?

Comment: @kaine 1. Qg5+ Qxg5

Comment: Knight at H8 to G6?  Nope biship B1 v knight

Comment: Rook at H5 to e5?  Nope c4 e6\

Comment: I think b8->d6 is also winning.

Comment: @DJClayworth 1... Kf6

Comment: Doesn't b4 delay the mate by 1 move?

Comment: @cHao It's white's move

Comment: I meant ...b4. To block the queen. But i was looking at the board wrong. :P

Answer (score 20):

**@boboquack** found the **only solution**. The following list shows suggestions from comments and other answers together with their refutation. You can click each link to show an image/animation.

> - [1.d8=Q (invalid move, pawn is pinned)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygyJ0.png)
>
>   [1.dxc8=Q+ Bb7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDagY.gif)
>
>   [1.dxc8=N+ Ke8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFw42.gif)
>
>   [1.Rxe5+ Be6+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYunh.gif)
>
>   [1.Qxe5+ Be6+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN6Tm.gif)
>
>   [1.Ng6+ Bxg6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK0PQ.gif)
>
>   [1.Nf5+ Bxf5+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjQ69.gif)
>
>   [1.Bd6+ Kf6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjWFR.gif)
>
>   [1.Bh4+ Rg5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqIWK.gif)
>
>   [1.Qg5+ Qxg5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmhK7.gif)

Comment: What about moving d7 to d8 and promoting to queen?

Comment: @RickvanOsta It's at the top of the list.

Answer (score -1):

> Knight to G6, right?

No capture
No escape for King in any direction.

Comment: Nope: 1. ... Bxg6

Comment: The bishop at b1 captures.

Answer (score -1):

> White queen at e3 takes black queen at e5

This should mate the king

Edit: did not see that a bishop could block this.  This is not a mate.

Comment: K escapes to F8

Comment: @xQbert F8 is guarded by bishop at H6

Comment: At true  missed that

Comment: How about: bishop at c4 moves to e6, blocking check?

Comment: @psmears touche.  didn't see that

Comment: I think bob has it.  I can't see a way around it.

Comment: As @psmears said, this isn't a mate.

Answer (score -1):

Knight, D4 to F5. I think this meets the criteria.

Comment: Nope, Bxf5 prevents mate.

Answer (score -1):

What about moving the bishop from g3 to h4.

Seems like a winner to me.

Comment: The refutation for this was already posted: [Rg5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqIWK.gif)

Comment: Ah didn't see that. I don't know what the chess abbreviations mean

Comment: Therefore I added animations to the list above. And there is only one solution.

Comment: Right but I didn't want to click and wait for every animation to find the move I was thinking of. It would've been easier to just write the moves in plain English

Comment: I doubt it would be easier, it would be too long and nobody would read it. [The chess notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_notation) isn't really that complicated. Usually it's the name of the piece + target square.

Answer (score -3):

I have a solution that can be given in just nine characters, but Stack Exchange demands that an answer be at least 30 characters long.  So now that I've satisfied that restriction:

> d7xc8 = N

Comment: Nope: 1. ... Ke8

Comment: doesn't work, king esxapes to e8

Comment: The king can't escape to e8 if the pawn is queened instead of knighted (or any other sufficiently mobile piece), and the knight isn't needed because of the rook on a7, but the bishop can block h1 to b7.